# Why does the DataGridView show a non-valid bottom row and hide the top row when hitting tab or down-arrow, and how can I prevent it?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that, if I press the down-arrow or tab key when on the last row, displays a non-existent bottom row (it's just a gray horizontal "mass") that hides the top row/scrolls it out of view.

I don't like this. How can I prevent it?

### UPDATE

I added this code just after the creation and population code, and it makes no difference:

```
int rowHeight = dataGridViewPlatypus.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed);   
int colWidth = dataGridViewPlatypus.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed);
dataGridViewPlatypus.Size = new Size(colWidth, rowHeight);
```

Comment: does the grid support additions of new rows?  is that the row you're seeing?  (it would have a * in the row header)

Comment: No, it's just a gray strip across the bottom, the width and height of all the other rows, but no * appears in it (unless it is the same shade gray as the row's background, "invisible" like stripes on a black panther).

Comment: Do you just mean the standard grey datagridview background showing at the bottom of the grid? Does this happen with just a very simple grid that you can show use the code for? It isn't clear exactly what you are seeing or how your produce it. I see the standard grey background but if my datasource has enough rows to fill the control then this does not show at the bottom.

Comment: @David Hall: Normally it looks perfect, but if I navigate down to the last row, THEN the "extra" (but blank) row displays. The rows and columns are created dynamically and then populated with the appropriate values; users can then edit certain cells, too, which is where I see this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

to hide according to size of the datasource you just have to modify the Row size of DataGridView.

like

```
dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(columnSize, rowSize);
```

Comment: I don't know what the two args are supposed to be - the width and height of the DGV?

Comment: I tried this and it made no diffrenct:

dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(
 dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height);

Comment: Well, like I said, that's what I tried, and it made no difference.